# How prove this inequality: $\frac{x^3+1}{\sqrt{x^4+y+z}}+\frac{y^3+1}{\sqrt{y^4+z+x}}+\frac{z^3+1}{\sqrt{z^4+x+y}}\geq2\sqrt{xy+yz+zx}$

Tags: inequality

Let $x,y,z>0$ such that $xyz=1$. Show that: $$\dfrac{x^3+1}{\sqrt{x^4+y+z}}+\dfrac{y^3+1}{\sqrt{y^4+z+x}}+\dfrac{z^3+1}{\sqrt{z^4+x+y}}\geq2\sqrt{xy+yz+zx}$$

I've tried many things but all failed. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: This looks like fun

Answer (score 5):

proof: since
\begin{align*}2\sqrt{(x^4+y+z)(xy+zx+yz)}&=2\sqrt{[x^4+xyz(y+z)][xy+yz+xz]}\\
&=2\sqrt{(x^3+y^2z+yz^2)(x^2y+
x^2z+xyz)}
\end{align*}
Use AM-GM inequality  we have
$$2\sqrt{(x^3+y^2z+yz^2)(x^2y+x^2z+xyz)}\le x^3+y^2z+yz^2+x^2y+x^2z+xyz=(x+y+z)(x^2+yz)=\dfrac{(x+y+z)(x^3+1)}{x}$$
so
$$\dfrac{x^3+1}{\sqrt{x^4+y+z}}\ge\dfrac{2x\sqrt{xy+yz+xz}}{x+y+z}$$
so
$$\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{x^3+1}{\sqrt{x^4+y+z}}\ge\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{2x\sqrt{xy+yz+xz}}{x+y+z}=2\sqrt{xy+yz+xz}$$